# Getting recursive formula to since solution

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there any way to get the recursive formula of the form $r_n=\alpha r_{n-1}+\beta$ to single formula as a function of $n$. I've seen results that find single formula as function of $n$ for geometric series and such but can't seem to find any literature or results for this type.

Comment: See [this](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/222/rec.pdf).

Comment: aren't those of the form $r_n=\alpha r_{n-1}+\beta r_{n-2} $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $\alpha \ne 1$, ${r_n}=\alpha {r_{n-1}}+\beta \Rightarrow {r_n}+\frac{\beta }{\alpha -1}=\alpha \left( {r_{n-1}}+\frac{\beta }{\alpha -1} \right)$.

Comment: Perovided $\alpha\ne1$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Yes, thanks.

Comment: I guess Im not completely seeing why this is helpful, Ive never been very good at these types of questions

Comment: @Kamster This shows that $\left \{ r_n + \frac {\beta} {\alpha -1} \right \}$ is a geometric progression.